# Can't do Postgresql manipulation in Heroku Database

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, knex.js, heroku-postgres

I am deploying a database and back-end of a simple web app to heroku. However, when I use knex.js to try to add data to the database, it does not work... (The error message says 'Unable to register' when I use postman to test the server).

My connection to back-end (express.js) is as follow

```
const postgres = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
     connectionString : process.env.DATABASE_URL,
     ssl: true,
  }
});
```

The code that "register" the user to the database (I insert to the login table as well since it has to be a transaction)

```
app.post("/register",(req,res)=>{
const {email,name,password} = req.body;
if(!email || !name || !password){
    return res.status(400).json('Incorrect form submission')
}
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
postgres.transaction((trx) => {
    trx.insert({
        hash: hash,
        email: email
    })
    .into('login')
    .returning('email')
    .then(logInEmail => {
        return trx('users')
        .returning('*')
        .insert({
            email: logInEmail[0],
            name: name,
            joined: new Date()
        }).then(user => {
            console.log(user[0])
            res.json(user[0]);
        })
    })
    .then(trx.commit)
    .catch(trx.rollback);
})
.catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register'))
})
```

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17qps.png)
Verification image that I connected my database

When I connect the server to my computer's database (Postgresql), I am still able to register for user as normal, but when I use the Heroku database, this doesn't work.

I am sorry this is a long post and I would really appreciate any help. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

The error message is:

```
{
"message": "insert into \"login\" (\"email\", \"hash\") values ($1, 
  $2) returning \"email\" - column \"email\" of relation \"login\" 
 does not exist"
 }
```

Comment: Try to change `err => res.status(400).json('unable to register')` line to `err => res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })` to get info about which error caused returning 400.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the error message

Answer (score 0):

You don't have column name `email` in your table `login`. Maybe you have not initialized your database schema.